# Line break issue in sql

Tags: php, sql, database

I have stored text in my database with 'Type: text'.

```
-This is a line

-This is a new line

-This is another line.
```

When I tried to retrieve the data. This is what I get.

```
-This is a line-This is a new line-This is another line.
```

How can I tell on my database to not ignore the line break.

This is how I print my query.

```
$query = "SELECT text FROM my_text";

$mysql_query = mysql_query
echo $mysql_result_text = mysql_result($mysql_query, '0', 'text');
```

Comment: save it with "\n" in between the strings or if you're displaying it via browser use '<br>'

Comment: can you please add code on how you print your query result?

Comment: When you output it to the browser, it ignores white space, use the [`nl2br`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function to get it to display correctly in the browser.  It's not an issue with the database.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is the meaning of this:

```
$query = "SELECT text FROM my_text";

$mysql_query = mysql_query
echo $mysql_result_text = mysql_result($mysql_query, '0', 'text');
```

I think, this code below is what you mean:

```
$mysql_query = "SELECT text FROM my_text";
echo $mysql_result_text = mysql_result($mysql_query, '0', 'text');
```

You could check this PHP script below to create a line break from the source:

```
$mysql_query = "SELECT text FROM my_text";
$mysql_result_text = mysql_result($mysql_query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mysql_result_text)) {
    echo $row['text'] . "\n";
}
```

Or this PHP script if you wish to have a `<br />` tag on the source:

```
$mysql_query = "SELECT text FROM my_text";
$mysql_result_text = mysql_result($mysql_query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mysql_result_text)) {
    echo $row['text'] . "<br />\n";
}
```

---

Now, if the output is all from the same field and not from separate rows, you could check this if using a `<pre>` tag would work:

```
$mysql_query = "SELECT text FROM my_text";
echo $mysql_result_text = "<pre>" . mysql_result($mysql_query, '0', 'text') . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Unless the output is all from the same field, not separate rows.